# query statement for mysql search results (connecting 4 tables)

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I have multiple tables in a database that need to be linked together for search results. I had an easy search going when just searching through 2 of the tables. but when I set it up to search through 4 tables I keep getting errors.

My Query:

```
 $query="
        SELECT spusername.*, sprecord.*, sptraining.*, splocation.* 
        FROM spusername, sprecord, sptraining, splocation
        WHERE (spusername.id = sprecord.spusername_id AND splocation.id = spusername.splocation_id) 
        AGAINST('%".$search."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY lastname ASC";
```

My errors:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AGAINST('%Bell%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY lastname ASC' at line
>   4 SELECT spusername.*, sprecord.*, sptraining.*, splocation.* FROM
>   spusername, sprecord, sptraining, splocation WHERE (spusername.id =
>   sprecord.spusername_id AND splocation.id = spusername.splocation_id)
>   AGAINST('%Bell%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY lastname ASC
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in  >C:\wamp\www\CRUD\searchresultv2.php on line 56
>   Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1  0.0011  686792  {main}( )   ..\searchresultv2.php:0
>   2  0.0136  694632  mysql_num_rows ( )  ..\searchresultv2.php:56

My other code that works:

```
$query="SELECT u.*, t.* FROM users u
  INNER JOIN training t ON (u.id = t.users_id)
  WHERE MATCH( lastname, firstname, location, level, created, training, duration ) 
        AGAINST('%".$search."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY lastname, firstname, location, level, created, training, duration";
```

I want basically the same results as my working code, just using 4 tables instead of 2. But I am confused on how to INNER JOIN 3 more tables. when I tried it in the same format, it did not work.

Comment: What errors are you getting.  Just looking at the query -- all the  joined tables have to connect together in some way.  sptraining is not being connected/joined to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't say what errors your getting, but your SQL has at least the following issues:

1. You don't have any JOIN condition for SPTraining and will therefore "multiply" the number of rows produced from the other three tables by the number of rows in SPTraining.  This is *probably* not what you want.
2. You have an AGAINST keyword without a MATCH to name the columns to match against.
3. It's not generally good practice to use * to select all columns.  Instead name the columns you want returned.
4. You need to make sure to sanitize $search (or, better, use a parameterized query if allowed in this syntax) or else you're inviting people to put SQL statements into the search term and use SQL injection to attack your site.
5. You're using the "old" JOIN syntax.  Personally, I don't have a problem with it, others will tell you that you should use explicit JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of query is this?  What you want to?  First, check exactly what you want from each table then try to join the tables, your having tables without joinging them.  Have you forgot while posting?